# Creating a Circle on a Face and Connecting Geometry

Tags: edges, geometry, topology

I'm trying to create simple circular eyes to this model while making sure I maintain a mesh with quad topology but it's causing some weirdness on the surface.

Some steps I took to get here:

1. Created a new Circle mesh Object with 8 vertices
2. Used the *Shrinkwrap Modifier* to project the geometry onto main body
3. Joined the two objects
4. Deleted the face that the circle was on
5. Filled the mesh making sure that there were only quads

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Weird lighting/surface]
[image: Geometry]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a simple circle on the surface, follow these steps:

1. In Edit Mode use <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to create two Loop Cuts to get vertex at the center of the future circle
2. Select the vertex obtained at the intersection of the two Loop Cuts and press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to Bevel vertex.
3. In the dialog box to the bottom left, change the Segments count to 2 and the Shape value to 0.09
4. Create supporting edges around the circle by selecting two vertecies and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to keep topology tidy
5. Remove unnecessary faces

[image]

Comment: +1 for the interesting non-addon solution

Comment: Awesome, I'll play around with this! Thank you for going out of your way to provide an example similar to mine!

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty nifty built-in add-on called [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html). Enable it via menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools*

[image]

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode. Select the face that requires a hole and click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Subdivide* and change the *Number of Cuts* in the tool options panel that appears in the lower left corner.

[image]

Select some inner faces where the circlular hole should be inscribed into then click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle*

[image]

To further give it a prettier quad topology with a nice face loop around the circle, press <kbd>I</kbd> to [`Inset Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) and slowly move your mouse towards the center of the circle then click <kbd>LMB</kbd>. Press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Faces* to create the circular hole.

[image]

You can get rid of the surrounding [N-Gons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#:%7E:text=An%20n%2Dgon%20is%20a,often%20define%20a%20polygon%20accordingly.) by adding the highlighted faces and keep a quad topology. The trick is to subdivide using even numbers like 4,6,8, etc. To cut those lines through the mesh, just select two (2) vertices at a time and press <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried playing around with this method at first but didn't know how to get rid of the surrounding n-gons so this helps a lot!