How to do a circle?
I want to make my first model from keyboard (keyboard from a laptop). The letter will be "O" and basically I don't know anything from Blender.
Earlier I added this addon(from another post which I understood like 0)

I want to make a button like "O" circle and button thing that circle stands on.


You could use the text option to create an O.

I really think that you should watch some beginner tutorial videos on using Blender before you try to start modelling objects with it. There are many ways of creating your 'O' which don't require the Curve Extra Objects addon such as adding and then manipulating a Mesh Circle or Cylinder but it depends how you want it to look. This is not a tutorial site but we can help if you get stuck. It would also help if you could add an image of what you're trying to model into your question with the edit link.

Hello, as John pointed out, it's best to go through some absolute beginner tutorials first before posting on this site. I've linked a question that's very similar to yours to assist you with modeling a circular area on a surface. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270860/creating-a-circle-on-a-face-and-connecting-geometry

Since you don't know much about blender here is a step-by-step on how to make the O letter

Create the button shape



Add circle



Insert face with 'I' and delete it with 'X' then faces



Then scale the O letter to fit in the button then 'E' to extrude it



Final shape


You can also use the text object to make the letter O, then Right click > Convert to > Mesh
